# Server 2012 Essentials not deleting backups

Tags: backup, windows-server-2012

I have a client who had 2012 essentials, he has a separate solution for backups and we don't want to use the built in Windows backup.

I selected each pc and turned backups off and told it to delete the backups it had saved. But two days and two restarts later they are still there taking up 135 very need GBs.

How can I get it to delete them? Just manually delete the files?

Comment: manually delete those files, and then let system reboot. and I know that you are not planning to use this feature but to make sure that there's no inconsistency within this and VSS which you will use later start backup_MMC and let it read that there's no files any more.

Answer (score 0):

Either you delete the backup files or have the system do it. Depending on the destination for the storage, make sure you have read/write/modify privileges so that you can access the directory to remove the files. If you're not going to use the backup files, than it really doesn't matter who deletes them to reclaim that space so that you can clear up room for your preferred backup solution.